# How can I fix this batch file to write in a text file in spaces?

Tags: python, syntax

I need help with fixing my code. I don't know whats wrong with it but it gives me an invalid syntax error on the else: command, Please be as simple as possible, and not be too complicated, I'm new to this.

```
def myName(my_name):        #What does this do?
    myName = input("What is my name? ")
    if(myName == #{my_name}):
        print ("Correct!")
    else:             #Gives invalid syntax error!
        print ("In-Correct!")

myName(Jacob)
```

Oh and what does the def variable() do?

Comment: Your subject doesn't match your question.  Can you fix?

Answer (score 1):

- Your code is a python script, not a batch file.
- `#{my_name}` is meaningless in Python (it is from Ruby)
- `def variable()` def-ines a function called `variable`.

Replace `#{my_name}` with `my_name` in your `if` statement,  replace `myName(Jacob)` with `myName("Jacob")`, and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    def myName(my_name):        #What does this do?
      myName = input("What is my name? ")
      if myName == my_name:
        print "Correct!"
      else:             #Gives invalid syntax error!
        print "In-Correct!"
    myName('Jacob')
```

I'm never done Python before, but tried this out at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php which is pretty handy!

You have to put the input value in quotes, eg. "Jacob" else it treats it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but like the alert says, the syntax is invalid.

First, in python the end of an if-conditional is denoted by a colon(:)

Second, hashtags(pound symbol, etc.) are always interpreted as the start of a single line comment.

Finally, using the `def` keyword denotes that you are creating a function.

so in your first line

```
if(myName == #{my_Name}):
```

everything after the hashtag is ignored for the line. Which to the interpreter means that there is a missing closing parenthesi, a missing colon, and the other side of the equality test is missing.

Also to get the correct result, you want to remove the curly brackets that are surrounding "my_name" otherwise it will always be false since you will essentially be creating a dictionary with the undefined element named my_name

Incorrect behavior:

```
>>> def myName(my_name):        #What does this do?
        myName = input("What is my name? ")
        if(myName == {my_name}):
            print ("Correct!")
        else:             #Gives invalid syntax error!
            print ("In-Correct!")


>>> bob = "bob"
>>> myName(bob)
What is my name? bob
In-Correct!
```

Correct Behavior:

```
def myName(my_name):        #What does this do?
        myName = input("What is my name? ")
        if(myName == my_name):
            print ("Correct!")
        else:             #Gives invalid syntax error!
            print ("In-Correct!")


>>> bob = "bob"
>>> myName("bob")
What is my name? bob
Correct!
>>> myName("bob")
What is my name? phil
In-Correct!
```

Since you are just starting, I would recommend learning the basic syntax of Python before anything.

[Code Academy: Python Syntax](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/introduction-to-python-6WeG3/0/1?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096)

[TutorialsPoint: Python Syntax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

After that you can learn to utilize the more powerful features that this language provides.